# Screen is cropped by a few pixels

Tags: screen, configuration, settings, location

I just installed Ubuntu, and for a while (2 weeks) the screen was fine. But my brother started tweaking the settings in Tweaks & Settings. He modified the scale setting in the displays section. (He put it back to normal) But the screen got a tad cropped. Unfornately, I can't give a screenshot because when I do them, I get the whole screen (I can see the rest of the arrows that are at the top and bottom of the scrollbars in Brave.) Note, however, it was okay at first, so where could I find those config files that were modified to delete?

Comment: He changed the scale option in the displays. He put it back, but it will still be cropped. I tried rebooting. Still croppped. I mean, it is neglible, you know only a few pixels off each side, but it is noticeable.

Comment: You need to determine exactly what it was that he did and change it back.  If the problem still exists, then you haven't found it yet. In order for us to help, we also need to know what was done.

Comment: I wish I could tell you more, but all I know is that he changed the zoom percentage. But, on the other hand, could I delete or modify a certain file in the `/etc` directory. That is the only place it could be because my brother has the same problem on his account.  Do you know where that would be?

Comment: What file are you talking about?  Do you happen to use a television as a display with overscan enabled?

Comment: No, we use a regular Samsung desktop monitor. It is not a laptop, its a desktop machine.

Comment: Press Auto Set on monitor.

Comment: I did already. It just centers the cropped screen.